# Dependency tree depth with npm ls

Tags: node.js, npm

I wrote a tool that given a NodeJS project calculate its dependency tree in a format I need. It is based on npm ls command:

```
npm ls --parseable=true --long=true --production
```

I noticed that sometime this command reaches a maxdepth and a line like this is printed:

```
.../bn.js:bn.js@"^0.15.0"::MAXDEPTH
```

When MAXDEPTH appear the dependency tree reached its max. I have now few questions:

1. What is the default max depth for npm ls (I didn't find this info in the doc)?
2. With a limited MAXDEPTH, do I omit some dependencies?
3. How can I have an infinite MAXDEPTH?
4. Is it convenient have an infinite MAXDEPTH?

Thx

Comment: You can overwrite depth by `--depth=<value>`  example `--depth=90`

Comment: Is there a way to an infinite value? If no, can you tell me the default value so that I can specify a greater value?